# Use the selected value of Dropdown list (value from database)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to use the value of the selected item from a Dropdown list to evaluate a condition. Please note that the value of DropTraining is from the database and consist of alphanumeric characters (ex: TRN-2015-2354)

Here is my initial code that I tried:

```
string valueTrain = DropTraining.SelectedValue; //put the value of droplist to valueTrain

    if (valueTrain == null)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(),
    "alert",
    "alert('The Training value is empty. Select value.');",
    true);
    }
    else
    { //code to execute if the valueTrain is not empty/null
```

It runs, but even I meant to select nothing from the DropTraining, it still executes the else statement.
Can you please suggest a way/method for me to use the said value, or anything that may solve this, cheers

Comment: If the value isn't an int (ex. `TRN-2015-2354`), how do you want it to become an int?

Comment: So if the string consists of not only numbers, but also other non-numeric characters, how is the `int.Parse` method suppose to know how to handle it?

Comment: You could split your string using `var splitted = valueTrain.Split('-')` and `Int32.Parse(splitted[1])` or `Int32.Parse(splitted[2])`

Comment: Can't we just ask him the constructor of `DropTraining`? What variable type did he use there, string or int? Also, try using int.TryParse(), it is very closely suited to your case of 'checking' if it can be parsed into int since it returns a boolean of whether parsing worked or not.

Comment: Hi all, apologies for that. I did edited my whole question. Hope y'all can still help me, im trying to learn. Thanks

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen and to kiziu That is my initial thought, to convert it to int for me to create a condition on the if statement. But yea since its alphanumeric its non sense.

Comment: If you just want to check if the string is empty there's the `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` and/or `String.IsNullOrEmpty`

Answer (score 1):

You can use it, selected value MUST be integer.

> (ex: TRN-2015-2354) this is not integer.

```
string selected = drp.SelectedItem.Text;
```

Or

```
string selected = drp.SelectedItem.Value;
```

AND

```
int x = int.Parse(selected.ToString());
```